# Ubuntu in Israel?

Tags: calendar, localization, hebrew

Is it possible to use Ubuntu in Israel? Someone in Israel would use the hebrew keyboard and probably the [Hebrew calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_calendar%E2%80%8E). Is it therefore possible to use the Hebrew calendar in Ubuntu? Is it possible to write hebrew from right to left?

Answer (score 1):

you can add hebrew keyboad layout just search keyboard and select keyboard layout

then in layouts tab select "+" button and add hebrew keyboard layout

Comment: i don't know about the calender but i think customization or some other similar indicator will be present

Answer (score 0):

yes. it is very simple.
In the installation process choose the Hebrew as language, and Hebrew keyboard layout.

about Hebrew calender, there a lib called libhdate and program (Hdate) base on that. you can find it in ubuntu software center.
it is very simple program, not something special. 
i'm working on something better, maybe it will be released soon

Additionally, you have the website of [Ubuntu Israel](http://ubuntu-il.org/)

Comment: Any evolution on this?  Because someone is asking about a Hindi and Gregorian calendar (which is similar to your solution)